# Plain SQL Pagination

Tags: sql, pagination, attunity

We want to implement pagination with plain SQL, but can't use a few important keywords because of the legacy database not understanding them. The goal is to get 20 entries instead loading and programmatically paginating 15,000 entries.

They keywords that don't work:

- `top N`
- `offset N`
- `rownum`
- `limit N`

Is there any way to achieve **pagination with plain old SQL** (no database functions)?

---

The JDBC bridge to the legacy system is Attunity, below that is an HP NonStop database. We are trying to develop the query in DBVisualizer.

The error message for `rownum` is

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 42S22]  JBC0016E: Remote call failed (return code=-202). JBC0091W: Untranslatable Message: [A033] A column by the name 'rownum' was not found.
```

*Update*:

We do have something that looks like numerical primary keys. I am saying it looks like, as we are not sure about the purpose of those numbers. Those numbers do indeed increase like a sequence.

```
13771
13821
15461
20008
21253
23838
23929
26666
```

Comment: Do you have a numerical primary key column?

Comment: Nothing like an Oracle sequence, but something that looks like it. See the update in my question.

Comment: Maybe use cursors?

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for limit in Attunity SQL is LIMIT TO X ROWS.  That syntax will limit the number of rows to that you set X to.

Comment: add some description